# How much memory is lost on startup

Tags: memory

I was wondering the following: As I start my computer and Xubuntu, it starts many programs before the login screen. Is it possible to measure by Valgrind the total number of lost bytes during startup? Something like

```
For every program i do
  valgrind i
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a process is terminated the allocated memory will be set as free

A memory leak can only occur while a process is running.

You could use valgrind to instrument and analyze the process that are still running once your machine is booted.

Answer (score 1):

There's a bit of a conundrum here: `valgrind` can't determine whether a process leaked memory until it is finished, and at that point, the issue is moot.

Also, not all software (including some common libraries) cleans up at exit, which will make it *appear* to leak memory.<sup>1</sup>  Although this is not something that's considered a good practice by many people, it does not create any genuine problems with regard to normal use.

**Keep in mind that the context of a memory leak is limited to the process that leaks it.**  After the process is finished, the system reclaims all of the memory used, whether it was "leaked" or not.  If there's an application you are wondering about, you can run it specifically in valgrind (keeping in mind my point in the last paragraph).  However, most of the stuff in distro repos has probably already gone through this anyway, so unless you are really familiar with the product (and its source code) you are unlikely to find anything.

---

<sup>1. Which can make debugging applications which use such libraries a bit of a hassle, gripe gripe.</sup>